# Unable to use json body of gcp cloud scheduler in cloud function as parameter value?

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, serverless, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a cloud scheduler which I am using to trigger my cloud function as http call, In my cloud function I would like to form a query (which should be dynamic). To do so, I am passing some parameter from cloud scheduler (Json Body), but when I trigger my cloud function it doesn't take parameter values which are coming from cloud scheduler as json body. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

json body from cloud scheduler:

```
{ 
   "unit":"QA",
   "interval":"3"
}
```

Cloud function code:

```
def main(request):

    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    if request_json and 'unit' in request_json:
        retail_unit = request_json['unit']
    elif request_args and 'unit' in request_args:
        retail_unit = request_args['unit']
    else:
        unit = 'UAT'

    if request_json and 'interval' in request_json:
        interval = request_json['interval']
    elif request_args and 'interval' in request_args:
        interval = request_args['interval']
    else:
        interval = 1

    query = "select * from `myproject.mydataset.mytable` where unit='{}' and interval ={}".format(                                                                                                    
    unit,interval)
    client = bigquery.Client()
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    dest_dataset = client.dataset(destination_dataset, destination_project)
    dest_table = dest_dataset.table(destination_table)
    job_config.destination = dest_table
    job_config.create_disposition = 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED'
    job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'
    job = client.query(query, location='US', job_config=job_config)
    job.result()
```

Note: It works when I pass same variables from cloud scheduler as argument values in http url (https://my-region-test-project.cloudfunctions.net/mycloudfunction?unit=QA&interval=3)

Comment: It might be ether utf-8 issue or you need to parse raw output, for hints see these other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53216177/http-triggering-cloud-function-with-cloud-scheduler

Comment: @Pentium10 Mentioned link works for me, and you are right the issue was with utf-8 and now it is resolved. Thank you so much. I made below changes in my code: 

raw_request_data = request.data
string_request_data = raw_request_data.decode("utf-8")
request_json: dict = json.loads(string_request_data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best hint is UTF-8 issue.

Check out also the situations described in this other thread:
[HTTP Triggering Cloud Function with Cloud Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53216177/http-triggering-cloud-function-with-cloud-scheduler)

Answer (score 8):

**You can override the default `Content-Type`** by [creating the cron job](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/http) using `gcloud` with the flag [`--headers Content-Type=application/json`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/http#--headers).

For instance:

```
gcloud scheduler jobs create http my_cron_job \
  --schedule="every 5 hours" \
  --uri="https://${ZONE}-${PROJECT_ID}.cloudfunctions.net/${FUNCTION_NAME}" \
  --http-method=POST \
  --message-body='{"foo": "bar"}' \
  --headers Content-Type=application/json
```

<s>This doesn't seem to be available from the GCP Console level yet.</s> Update 08/2021: It seems that it has been implemented in the UI now:

[image: scheduler headers]

---

Alternatively, using `force=True` seems to help if you're using Flask:

```py
request.get_json(force=True)
```

This is due to the fact that Cloud Scheduler seems to set the default `Content-Type` header to `application/octet-stream`. See the [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you created your scheduler job as below:

```bash
gcloud scheduler jobs create http job_name \
  --schedule="5 * * * *" \
  --uri="https://${CLOUD_FUNCTION_URI}" \
  --http-method=POST \
  --message-body='{"unit":"QA", "interval":"3"}'
```

Here is how I'll get the data:

```py
import json

def main(request):

    request_data = request.get_data()
    json_data = json.loads(request_data.decode())
    
    print(json_data)
```

```json
{ 
   "unit":"QA",
   "interval":"3"
}
```