# Cloud Scheduler ERROR with status INTERNAL for an HTTP target

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to use Cloud Scheduler to schedule a Cloud Function (HTTP target) on a weekly basis.

Unfortunately, when I try to force a run the function, I get this error:

```
{
httpRequest: {
status: 500
}
insertId: "op2w2lfi2zmuu"
jsonPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
jobName: "projects/my-project-id/locations/us-central1/jobs/my-job-name"
status: "INTERNAL"
targetType: "HTTP"
url: "https://my-http-trigger.a.run.app/"
}
logName: "projects/my-project-id/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-05-16T12:37:06.594694219Z"
resource: {
labels: {3}
type: "cloud_scheduler_job"
}
severity: "ERROR"
timestamp: "2023-05-16T12:37:06.594694219Z"
}
```

Some details about my scheduler job:

- service account running the job is properly set up and has cloud run invoker role
- Auth Header is OIDC token
- Audience is set up as the following: https://my-http-trigger.a.run.app/
- Ingress Settings of my cloud functions are *Allow All Connections*

[see details the cloud scheduler execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbd7m.png)

I was expecting the cloud scheduler run to have a success status (as my cloud function is running without errors) but I got `status of last execution = failed`

Comment: I think the code in your function is crashing.

Comment: Did you found out the problem? we got the same problem and we don't know where the error is coming from

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing data to the cloud function from the Cloud Scheduler body? I was getting the same error and what I had to do was to change in the Cloud Scheduler the 'content-type' to 'application/json' as before it was 'application/octet-stream'. Now the data passed successfully and the cloud function ran.

For fer[HTTP Triggering Cloud Function with Cloud Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087505/unable-to-use-json-body-of-gcp-cloud-scheduler-in-cloud-function-as-parameter-va)